# Particular $f \in C_c^1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

is there a way to construct a function $f \in C_c^1( B(0,\frac{3R}{4}))$ such that $f|_{B(0,\frac{R}{2})}=1, \quad f|_{B(0,\frac{3R}{4})^C}=0$ and $0\le f\le 1$ everywhere such that $|Df(x)| \le \frac{4}{R}$ for almost all $x \in B(0,R)?$

I currently don't see how to do it, but often there are some nice tricks how such functions can actually be constructed and maybe I am lucky and anybody here knows how it can be done?

Edit: This question has already an answer, but I suspect that the answer assumes that $f \in C^2$ and might therefore be wrong. This is so, since Taylor's formula is applied up to order $2$ and I guess that this demands $f \in C^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Think of small $h> 0.$ Then by the MVT,

$$\tag 1 [f(3R/4)-f(\,(R/2)+h\,)]/(\,(R/4)-h) = f'(c_h)$$

for some $c_h \in (R/2+h,3R/4).$ But $f(3R/4)=0,$ and because $f(R/2)=1,f'(R/2) = 0,$ we have $f((R/2)+h) = 1+o(h).$

So the left side of $(1)$ equals

$$-(1+o(h)\,)/(\,(R/4)-h\,).$$

Now check that the absolute value of the above is $>4/R$ if $h>0$ is small enough.

---

For your revised problem let's normalize (I should have done that to begin with.) For $a>0,$ define

$$f_a(x) = \begin{cases} 1,0\le x\le 1\\ 
(1+\cos (a (x-1)))/2, 1\le x \le 1+(\pi/a)\\
0, x\ge 1+(\pi/a) \end{cases}.$$

Extend $f_a$ to $\mathbb {R}$ by making $f_a$ even. Then $f_a\in C^1(\mathbb {R)},$ and $|(f_a)'(x)|\le a/2$ for all $x.$ Verify that $f_a$ is a solution for the case $R=2$ for any $a\in (\pi,4).$ For any such $a,$ the general problem is then solved by $f_a(2x/R).$

Comment: thank you very much. I changed my question slightly now due to your answer. Do you think that now it is possible to construct such a function?

Comment: I've answered your second question.

Comment: you know that $f$ compactly supported means that the support is in a compact set of an open ball of radius $R$. If I see this correctly, then the support here is the closed ball of radius $R$.

Comment: by the way I am not so sure if your proof is correct as Taylor's formula assumes $f \in C^2$ at least, I think

Comment: I tweaked the example to give the desired compact support. Taylor was not used in either my first or second answer to your problem, so I'm not sure what you mean with that comment.

Comment: I thought that this is Taylor expansion $f((R/2)+h) = 1+o(h).$

Comment: It's just the definition of the derivative at $R/2$ knowing $f'(R/2)=0.$